# What is the right way to add gesture detection to a custom UIView used in a reusable UITableCellView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a custom UIView. Using my StoryBoard, I added a UIView widget to a UITableCellView that I had painted in my StoryBoard. I changed the class to my custom class (`ValveStatusView`). I made sure the `User Interaction Enabled` was clicked on. And I implemented the following in my class (in addition to the required `drawRect:` and other methods).

```
@implementation ValveStatusView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tap: (UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    NSLog(@"tapped");
}

...
```

But to no avail. I never see it logged. Can I not do it in the `init...` method? Or is there something else I need to implement in my subclass to enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add your custom view in storyboard then `initWithFrame` method is never called, that's why you don't have the tap gesture added.

You can add the gesture in `awakeFromNib` method of your `UIView`.

Not sure what you want to achieve, but this tap gesture can be handled with the UITableView delegate methods `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.